# Why does my game studder based on what I have selected in the hierarchy in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have no idea why this happens and I was wondering if there was a reason or maybe even a fix.
Vid link to what I'm talking about: https://youtu.be/HwxqL95lzXU

Answer (score 0):

The reason it occurs is that the editor has to update all changes made on whatever you have selected. On top of that, Unity will attempt to draw the gizmos related to the object you have selected and **all** child objects. Depending on the object you have selected, the number of updates that need to redraw the editor and/or the number of gizmos needed to be drawn can take up a lot of CPU, which causes lag.

The one solution I can think of is to click on `Gizmos` in the top right of the editor window, and uncheck the box `Selection Outline`. If there is not a noticeable enough difference, disabling all gizmos can also help.

Outside of these small changes, I am unsure if there is a way to heavily reduce CPU usage in editor when selecting objects in editor. I tend to never have objects selected while playing unless I need to track various data. Even if I do need to track data, it is not the entire gameObject, so I will selectively print data I need or track it with a custom editor tool.